# How to set up @media correctly?

Tags: css, media, responsive

I got some question about making the website responsive. I want to get the header to be smaller on 1024px screens. But my @media code won't work. What is wrong with my code. I'm fairly new and wanted to set up a website on the example of this German dude's tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHe17jODCKc&t=146s

HTML:

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1.0>
 <title>Jacob's Website</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Major+Mono+Display" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta:500" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

CSS:

```
/* HEADER *******************************************************/

header {width: 100%; height: 65px; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; background: #fff; box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #e2e2e2; z-index: 1;}

#logo {width: 140px; float: left; margin: 10px 0 0 50px;}

#logo:hover {opacity: 0.5;}

#logo img {width: 100%;}

header nav {float:right; margin: 10px 50px 0 0; }

header nav ul li {float: left; margin-left: 25px;}

header nav ul li a {font-size: 14px;}

header nav ul li:hover {padding-top: 5px;}
```

The @media code for the header:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {header {height: auto;}}
```

If there's any more code that need's to be posted let me know!

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Does your header not have the computed property of `height: auto` when you inspect it in your browser's devtool? Can you include your markup where the `<header>` element is?

Comment: What do you expect height: auto; should do? "auto" will adapt to the content it contains, so if the inner content is large, it will not auto-magically squash everything and read your mind :)

Comment: I can assure you the `@media` query works. When the device is `screen` and `max-width` of viewport is lower than `1024px` the rule is read and applied. However, if you have another stronger rule applying at the same time, the above does not cancel it. Most likely, you want to wrap the stronger rule into `@media (min-width: 1024px){/* your rule here */}`

Comment: The `@media` query works as it should. If the style isn't being applied for you it might be because other styles are currently overruling it. In this case, if you have a style for `header` that isn't `height:auto` I'd recommend wrapping it within the following: `@media screen and (min-width:1025px) {...}`

Comment: Thats the effect i want to create, when max-width is lower 1024px: https://youtu.be/kHe17jODCKc?t=165

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with a mobile first approach.

Set the header height to something small like 65px then use min-width as a breakpoint.

```
header { height: 65px; } /* Will be applied on load */

@media (min-width: 1024px) { 
header { height: 200px; } /* Applied to viewport equal or larger than 1024px */ 
}
```

Test with that first then apply the auto height if it's ok. Maybe it's just that the auto height ain't doing what you want. Good luck !